# How to get covariance matrix from point cloud data using PCL library?

Tags: computer-vision, covariance, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I want a sample code that can get covariance matrix from point cloud data using PCL.

I looked at the PCL documentation and I found this code to calculate covariance:

```
// Placeholder for the 3x3 covariance matrix at each surface patch
Eigen::Matrix3f covariance_matrix;

// 16-bytes aligned placeholder for the XYZ centroid of a surface patch
Eigen::Vector4f xyz_centroid;

// Estimate the XYZ centroid
compute3DCentroid (cloud, xyz_centroid);

// Compute the 3x3 covariance matrix
computeCovarianceMatrix (cloud, xyz_centroid, covariance_matrix);
```

Comment: I am sorry for my unclear question. actually my problem is I have point cloud data and i want to calculate the covariance matrix from that data. I am a new student of computer vision major and I don't know how to get it that is why I ask this question just to get some direction from you guys. I am sorry again for my question.

Comment: I look in PCL Documentation and I found these code to estimate covariance: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/normal_estimation.php but I don't know how to start with it, like which header file should I include in the code,etc.

Comment: I think you need to start with the earlier tutorials: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/

Answer (score 2):

That is straight forward, but I guess you need more reading the documentations/tutorials :)

1- load the PCD file, for example:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> ());
pcl::io::loadPCDFile("c:\path\pcdfile.pcd",*cloud)
```

2- calculate the centroid:

```
Eigen::Vector4f xyz_centroid;
compute3DCentroid (cloud, xyz_centroid);
```

3- calculate the covariance

```
Eigen::Matrix3f covariance_matrix;
computeCovarianceMatrix (cloud, xyz_centroid, covariance_matrix);
```